# CORS ERROR for HLS nodejs and reactjs, when trying to stream the m3u8 on reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I know questions like this has been already asked but I have try to google it still didn't find the solution don't know what is wrong here, I have a nodejs server that is running on port `3001` and a react server that is running on port `3000`. I have a directory in the nodejs where `.m3u8` and `.ts` files exist also I have made that folder static using express

[image]

I am trying to stream the video on react on browser but I am getting this error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3001/post-processing/data/output.m3u8' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

[image]

**nodejs**

```
console.log(`Server running on PORT: ${PORT}`)
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
  });

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/post-processing/data/'))

const server = app.listen(PORT);

new hls(server, {
  provider: {
    exists: (req, cb) => {
      const ext = req.url.split(".").pop();

      if (ext !== "m3u8" && ext !== "ts") {
        return cb(null, true);
      }
      console.log("path join",__dirname + req.url)
      fs.access(__dirname + req.url, fs.constants.F_OK, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("url", __dirname + req.url);
          console.log("File not exist");
          return cb(null, false);
        }
        cb(null, true);
      });
    },
    getManifestStream: (req, cb) => {
      const stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + req.url);
      cb(null, stream);
    },
    getSegmentStream: (req, cb) => {
      const stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + req.url);
      cb(null, stream);
    },
  },
});
```

I have try to add this cors still getting same error

```
const corsOptions ={
  origin:'*', 
  credentials:true,            //access-control-allow-credentials:true
  optionSuccessStatus:200
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

**Reactjs**

```
function Feed() {
  return (
    <div className="feed">
      <ReactHlsPlayer
        src="http://localhost:3001/post-processing/data/output.m3u8"
        autoPlay={false}
        controls={true}
        width="100%"
        height="auto"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Feed;
```

Comment: found any solution? Even I am stuck